# How do I add API data into my MongoDB with Spark/Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-drill

I am working on a project with this API https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players and have been trying to add it into a database within MongoDB.

Is there a way to add it into MongoDB using Spark?

I was able to pull it up with Spark/Python as shown in the picture but now struggling to find a way to add it into a collection in a database within MongoDB. I have added json or csv files into Mongo before, but never straight from an API link. Here is what I have so far by adding getting the API link with Spark/Python. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqXTH.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: have you tried searching 'python save public API data to MongoDB'? here are few steps(you need spend more time on each step since these steps just rough ideas):
0. setup the python project with MongoDB
1. using python start an API call to https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players and get the response body
2. sanitize the response, and get the data you want from the response. hint: response.json()
3. save the data into MongoDB

Comment: So basically you get the data as json type. Now your job are: 1. Convert that Json data into Dataframe with schema; 2. Tranform, Clean, Extract your needed data from that DF; 3. Write that DF into Mongodb, pyspark already have libraries for that job (MongoDB Spark Connector) (check [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/master/python/write-to-mongodb/))